# Conditional re-render is re-rendering when setState is called with same value

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Every time I call `setState` on `isSignedIn` even when the value doesn't change, it seems to be re-rendering and setting the screen back to the initial screen of the stack.

```
const {isAuthenticated, isVerified} = useAuth();
const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => setIsSignedIn(isVerified && isAuthenticated), [isAuthenticated, isVerified]);

<NavigationContainer>
  <Root.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName}>
    {!isSignedIn ? (
      <Root.Screen
        name="Auth"
        component={AuthStack}
        options={globalOptions}
      />
    ) : (
      <>
        <Root.Screen
          name="Tab"
          component={TabStack}
          options={globalOptions}
        />
      </>
    )}
  </Root.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Your can prevent state change by adding an if condition.

Comment: If (!isVerified && isAuthenticated)  return

Comment: Then the rest of your code in the useeffect

Comment: @Schnecke Do you mean creating a const with an if condition and returning the appropriate stack? I tried that and it's still re-rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had a problem with the way I was setting `isVerified` that it would be set to true for a moment then false.

Problem code in my auth provider:

```
function updateIsVerified(user) {
    if (attemptedLoginMethod === 'facebook') {
      setIsVerified(true);
    } else {
      setIsVerified(user?.emailVerified ?? false);
    }
```

The `attemptedLoginMethod` was not being set to the correct method before `updateIsVerified` is called.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I can't mark it as a solution until tomorrow

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Done

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
useEffect(() => {
  if( isVerified && isAuthenticated ){
    setIsSignedIn(true);
  }
 }, [isAuthenticated, isVerified]
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still seems to be re-rendering